# .NET Core 2.2 Angular6 - There is an incomplete parameter in the route template

Tags: .net, angular, routes

I have a . net core/angular project that I try to run after generating another application but I get this error:

RoutePatternException: There is an incomplete parameter in the route template. Check that each '{' character has a matching '}' character.

[Error preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4dNP.png)

[Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5v98r.png)

Please see bellow Startup.cs

[Startup.cs](https://gist.github.com/06cae08faf1b64dc9546cac3ebd2f86c.git)

Thank you for your help !!

Comment: Hi @max, welcome to StackOverflow! You should post a [complete, minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code inside your question, external links are generally not allowed

Comment: Hey there, @max!

Did you check your routes in Controllers? Maybe there is a problem? :)
I don't think it's connected with Angular.

Cheers!

Comment: Hi @Ashiv.. Thank you a lot!!. you save my day. i was looking in the wrong place. In my controller i have this   [HttpGet("api/project/save}")] instead [HttpGet("api/project/save")] and that made evrything crash

Comment: Glad that I could help you @max! Take care!

Answer (score 0):

I know it is not the answer you are looking for but I would rather create a net core web API and then I would create a *separate* application with VSCode or Webstorm in "pure" angular. The scaffolding that Visual Studio creates it is not always great and can lead to messy code.